# What was the first movie depicting a bat wielding educational professional?

Tags: first-appearance

The tough education professional who wields a baseball bat to bring order to a troubled school has become something of a trope.  I'm wondering what the first appearance was.

[Morgan Freeman](http://c7.alamy.com/comp/BKGHCT/lean-on-me-1989-poster-BKGHCT.jpg) depicted the archetype in *[Lean on Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097722/)* (1989), but [Jim Belushi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093780/mediaviewer/rm2358381312) depicted the archetype in *[The Principal](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093780/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* (1987), co-starring with Lou Gosset, Jr. and Rae Dawn Chong:

[image]

There was an 1982 exploitation film *[The Class of 1984](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083739/)* that may have set the precedent for the two subsequent films, but I can't recall if the teacher in that film used a baseball bat specifically ([this movie poster suggests a lead pipe and blowtorch](http://www.gstatic.com/tv/thumb/movieposters/42755/p42755_p_v8_af.jpg), but many melee weapons were employed in the movie, and the iconic nature of the baseball bat wielding educational professional had not yet been established...)

- Was Belushi's the first depiction of this archetype, or is there an earlier example?

---

*Question amended to "bat wielding" to allow for cricket bats.*

Comment: Do you classify a cricket paddle as a bat? (in essence, it's a cricket bat. The _baseball_ bat may be an Americanisation of an earlier British trope) Or are you looking for a **baseball** bat specifically?

Comment: @Flater Great point and cricket paddle answers are definitely welcome.  (It's really the Herculean archetype of the "club hero". Spinal Tap has an iconic cricket paddle scene, and I think anyone interested in this question would appreciate hearing more about that part of the tradition.)  This question was intended to be about Americana, but if there's a legit precedent, I will vote for it!